# Why is multinomial coefficient satisfy ${p\choose k_1,k_2,...,k_b}\equiv 0 \pmod p$ if $k_i<p$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

show ${p\choose k_1,...,k_b}\equiv 0 \pmod p$. I have not practiced number theory for a while and in need of little help. I know $p$ is not divisible, and that the coefficient is a natural number. My attempt is: ${p!\over k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_b!}={(p-1)!\over k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_b!}\cdot p$. The question is whether or not ${(p-1)!\over k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_b!}$ is a natural number. Because $p$ is not divisible and ${p!\over k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_b!}$ is natural then ${(p-1)!\over k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_b!}$ is either natural or ${1\over p}$ (the only fraction possible). If it is the fraction above, then $p!=k_1!\cdot...\cdot k_b!$. Here, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $p$ is prime in the above question (implied by your saying "I know $p$ is not divisible [by anything other than 1 or itself]")

Note, one of the more useful definitions of prime numbers is the following:

> A number, $p$, is prime iff for every choice of integers $a,b$ if you have $p\mid a\cdot b$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

We know that $p$ divides the numerator of $\frac{p!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_b!}$ and we know the multinomial coefficient is an integer (because of its combinatorial interpretation).  We ask if $p\mid k_1!k_2!\cdots k_b!$

Suppose it is true that $p\mid k_1!\cdots k_b!$.

As $p$ is prime, that would imply that $p\mid k_i!$ for some $i$, but this is a contradiction since the prime decomposition of $k_i!$ would include only primes strictly smaller than $p$ (why?).

> Because $k_i<p$ you have $k_i!$ is a product of numbers, each of which smaller than $p$.  If it were true that $p\mid k_i!$, that would imply that $p\mid a$ for some $a$ with $0<a\leq k_i<p$ which is a contradiction.

Thus $p\not\mid k_1!\cdots k_b!$ and the multinomial coefficient is indeed divisible by $p$ since it is not cancelled by any term in the denominator.

Comment: Why is it implied that $p$ divides $k_1!...k_b!$?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel as a direct corollary of the definition of prime numbers that I give, if $p\mid a\cdot b\cdot c\cdots k$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ or $\cdots$ or $p\mid k$.  This can be proven via induction.

Comment: I am sorry to have forgotten to mention that $p$ is prime...It is a habit.

Comment: I know, but didn't quite understand the relation; were you referring the problematic case I gave to begin with?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel reworded the proof slightly.  Originally, my intention was to provide the last few steps of your partial proof.  I found it easier to just reword it from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the patience to refresh my memory on this.

Comment: Hate to bother you with this, but the next question asked to show that the coefficient is $1$ modulo $p$, if $k_i=p$ for some $i$; I just saw it should be equal $1$ literally. What is the point in the congruence? Have I got it wrong?

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel if $k_i=p$ exactly, then that implies all other terms should be zero (*since $\binom{n}{r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k}$ generally is defined so that $r_1+r_2+\dots+r_k=n$ and each term is a non-negative integer*), so it will be $\binom{p}{p}=1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, could you please elaborate why $p \nmid k_1!...k_b!$ implies that $p$ divides the multinomial coefficient (your last statement)?

Comment: @Dennis Because $p$ clearly divides $p!$ since $p!=p\cdot (p-1)!$, and since $\binom{p}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_b}\cdot k_1!k_2!\cdots k_b!=p!$ we know that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_b}\cdot k_1!k_2!\cdots k_b!$.  Now, noting that every term in the product there was an integer and since $p$ does not divide any of the factorials on the right and $p$ is prime, it follows that $p$ divides the multinomial coefficient since it is known that it had to have divided *something* in the product since $p$ is prime.